# Spark can not process recursive avro data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, recursive-datastructures, spark-avro

I have `avsc` schema like below:

```
{
  "name": "address",
  "type": [
     "null", 
        {
           "type":"record",
           "name":"Address",
           "namespace":"com.data",
           "fields":[
              {
                 "name":"address",
                 "type":[ "null","com.data.Address"],
                 "default":null
              }
           ]
        }
     ],
  "default": null
}
```

On loading this data in pyspark:

```
jsonFormatSchema = open("Address.avsc", "r").read()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("avro")\
.option("avroSchema", jsonFormatSchema)\
.load("xxx.avro")
```

I got such exception:

```
"Found recursive reference in Avro schema, which can not be processed by Spark"
```

I tried many other configurations, but without any success.
To execute I use with spark-submit:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a intended feature, you can take a look at the "issue" :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25718

Comment: I have avro files in such schema and I do not have impact on this. Can I somehow change schema to be able to read avro files?

Comment: @gorrch were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @BugsBuggy I used other package finally, but I do not remember now which since I changed project.

Comment: Well, I ended up using `DatumReader`.